# поиск элементов в массиве

Tags: java

Не подскажете есть ли метод по поиску элементов в массиве?
P.S поиск будет проводиться в массиве элементов с типом `char`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Преобразуйте массив к списку и вызовите `indexOf()` у списка

```
char[] data = {'a', 'c', 'b'};
int idx = Arrays.asList(data).indexOf('b');
```

А если массив отсортированный, то лучше вызвать `Arrays.binarySearch()`

```
char[] data = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(data, 'b');
```

Answer (score 0):

Увы ничего стандартного в java нет, приходится писать свои велосипеды:

```
 private static int find(char[] array, char element) {
    if (Objects.isNull(array))
        return -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] == element)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться библиотекой **Apache Commons Lang**, там есть утилитный класс `ArrayUtils` с методом [indexOf](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf-char:A-char-)

Comment: Есть `Arrays.binarySearch()` для сортированных массивов

Comment: ну да есть, только в вопросе же не про сортированные массивы речь

Comment: В вопросе ничего о сортировке не сказано

Answer (score 0):

Можно так попробовать:

```
private static int findChar(char[] array, char element) {
  return new String(array).indexOf(element);
}
```

Вернёт либо позицию символа в массиве, либо -1, в случае отсутствия.